# Android AVD rotating but not the apps

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a problem with the emulator. When I use Ctrl+F11 or Ctrl+F12 it rotate correctly but the app or the Android OS not did.
Here is an images showing it:

Portrait:
http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/9602/29083313.jpg

Landscape:
http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/5923/31565201.jpg

On landscape you can see the top bar showing at left instead of the top correct position like on my mobile phone. I already checked autorotation under the screen configuration on the emulator.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Check your android manifest. The activity that you are displaying should have a screenOrientation attribute, check if it is set. It should have a "portrait" value. This is causing your activity not to rotate. Erase it and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in the Android 2.3.x emulators. Assuming that your app is behaving normally in other emulators, there is nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: Excellent, I created a 2.2 emulator and it worked. Thank you very much :)
How could I imagine that? xD